# Add a break tag after every record, except the last record?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to add a break tag after every record, but not the last record?

Here's my partial code:

```
if($db->num_rows($query) > 0)
{       
    while($listing = $db->fetch_array($query))
    {
        eval("\$page .= \"".$templates->get("page_template")."\";");
    }
}
```

Kind regards.

Comment: Why the call to `eval()`? What happened to `$listing`?

Comment: I'm calling to `eval()` because it's a template. `$listing` is used inside the template so I can fetch database row information.

Comment: "I'm calling to eval() because it's a template. " --- what?!?!? It is not necessary even it is a template. Since you can use regulat `while` and `if` - you can also use assign operator as well.

Comment: I'm using `eval()` because it's part of a framework I'm using too.

Comment: @Spencer: Is your framework called PHP 5.3 ? I use it too, and I love it!

Comment: @greg0ire: No, actually I'm using MyBB as a framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: please don't use eval, there's no benefit to it in this situation and it poses a huge security risk. Second: the theory of "every item but the last" isn't that hard, as you've already got the total number. Something like this may work:

```
<?php
if($db->num_rows($query) > 0)
{
    $count = 0;
    while($listing = $db->fetch_array($query))
    {
        $page .= $templates->get("page_template");
        if( ++$count !== $db->num_rows( $query ) ) {
            // add break tag.
        }
    }
}
```

As an alternative (and a cleaner solution), you might want to implode an array of content:

```
<?php
while( $listing = $db->fetch_array( $query ) ) {
    $pages[] = $templates->get( 'page_template' );
}
$page = implode( 'break-tag', $pages );
```

Comment: Another solution would be to collect everything to one variable with brak tag after each record and after the loop - cut off the latest not needed tag with substr. Or - move adding tag before the adding the row itself for all rows except of 0th.

Comment: This is exactly what implode() was made for.. +1

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to have a counter, lets say `$i = 1`, and have all rows, lets say `$n = $db->num_rows($query)`.

You print `<br />` tags expect in the case where `$i == $n`
Else you print normal and increment `$i` by one.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the most graceful.

```
$row_count = $db->num_rows($query);
$i = 1;
if($row_count > 0)
{       
    while($listing = $db->fetch_array($query))
    {
        if($i == $row_count) { $tag = ""; }else{ $tag = "<br />"; }
// you need to put the $tag below.
    eval("\$page .= \"".$templates->get("page_template")."\";");
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are referring to a `<br/>` tag...

one way to implement it is to set a boolean for the first loop set to true. At the beginning of the loop, if the boolean is true, don't print anything, if not, print a `<br/>`. At the end of the first run, set it to false.  This way it prints out a `<br/>` just before the line but not before the first run and it won't print out after the final row.

```
if($db->num_rows($query) > 0)
{       
    $first_loop = true;    
    while($listing = $db->fetch_array($query))
    {
        if($first_loop !== true)
            echo "<br/>";
        eval("\$page .= \"".$templates->get("page_template")."\";");
        $first_loop = false;
    }
}
```